# Why isn't my analytics events getting registered?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

I have 3 links on my page. For each link I have a Javascript click event assigned.

Clicking on link 1 - I trigger the following event tracking:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'result page', 'click', 'content link', 'PDFdownload');
```

I tried looking in the report for events logged in as Analytics admin under “Behaviour > Event”, but can't seem to find anything registered on this.

What am I missing?

I naturally also added the following GA-snippet just after the `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-63478456-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Looking in the chrome profiler, I can see the event being sent and response seems ok also, but figure I perhaps need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because you have the format wrong

[Event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
Value   Type    Required    Description
Category    String  Yes Typically the object that was interacted with (e.g. button)
Action  String  Yes The type of interaction (e.g. click)
Label   String  No  Useful for categorizing events (e.g. nav buttons)
Value   Number  No  Values must be non-negative. Useful to pass counts (e.g. 4 times)
```

the last value should be a number not `'PDFdownload'`

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);  // value is a number.
```

Comment: Oh darn, well spotted - too bad GA doesnt throw any error back when doing that wrong - changed my label to the value instead and check LIVE-report that events are turning up now! Cheers man!

Comment: Unfortunately the measurement protocol pretty much just eats what ever you send it.